# Integrate wordpress blog into existing html site

Tags: blog

I've integrated wordpress to my website with the help of godaddy. I can access my blog via a sub domain. The them of this blog however is completely different to the rest of the site.

Am I right in saying that I need the html and css of that file to match the rest of the my site? What's the easiest way of going about this? Inside the blog directory there are hundreds of files, which ones do i need to edit?

Comment: Your wordpress site is under **blog** folder, Right ? And you want to changes blog posts html as per your requirement ?

Comment: You need to edit the CSS file inside your theme folder. `wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

If you have budget available, you may want to hire a developer to create a theme for you. If there's no budget, browse through the WordPress.org theme repository to find a theme that looks similar to the rest of your website. Don't worry too much about colors, think more about the overall layout - the placement of things and the size of the header. Some themes offer settings that will allow you to change the color scheme to more closely match your site. Others let you add custom CSS so you can tweak the colors that way.

If you find a theme that's close but the functionality isn't quite there, you may eventually want to consider creating a child theme - this takes most of the parent theme but lets you override whatever parts and pieces you wish. However this requires more knowledge of both PHP and CSS, so a theme that allows you to tweak colors and/or CSS is probably the easiest route.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your blog styling within the wp-content folder. There you will find basically everything you will need to edit your theme's styling and layout.

This will help you learn about how Wordpress layouts work and whats what. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/developer-super-cheat-sheet/?npp=b&utm_expid=3606929-84.YoGL0StOSa-tkbGo-lVlvw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

You can also use a starter theme such as https://underscores.me/ and basically biuld your own theme to match your current website.